# How to have text ellipses on right/left buttons with which are flexed to fill the viewport width in CSS?

Tags: css

I have this basically:

```css
.viewport {
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
    --color-dark: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-light: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-contrast: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-contrast-2: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    --color-base-contrast-3: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-background-2: rgb(244, 244, 244);
    --color-base-background-3: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    --color-base-background-4: rgb(222, 222, 222);
    --color-base-background-5: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    --color-green: hsl(165, 92%, 44%);
    --color-green-light: #77fcdb;
    --color-purple: rgb(121, 85, 243);
    --color-purple-light: #bd93f9;
    --color-yellow: rgb(246, 223, 104);
    --color-yellow-light: #f1fa8c;
    --color-red: rgb(238, 56, 96);
    --color-red-light: #ff5555;
    --color-blue: rgb(56, 201, 247);
    --color-blue-light: #8be9fd;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 0px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 16px;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
    max-width: 768px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
.link {
    --color-dark: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-light: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-contrast: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-contrast-2: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    --color-base-contrast-3: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-background-2: rgb(244, 244, 244);
    --color-base-background-3: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    --color-base-background-4: rgb(222, 222, 222);
    --color-base-background-5: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    --color-green: hsl(165, 92%, 44%);
    --color-green-light: #77fcdb;
    --color-purple: rgb(121, 85, 243);
    --color-purple-light: #bd93f9;
    --color-yellow: rgb(246, 223, 104);
    --color-yellow-light: #f1fa8c;
    --color-red: rgb(238, 56, 96);
    --color-red-light: #ff5555;
    --color-blue: rgb(56, 201, 247);
    --color-blue-light: #8be9fd;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 0px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: var(--color-base-contrast-2);
    color: var(--color-light);
}
  
.link-side {
    --color-dark: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-light: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-contrast: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-contrast-2: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    --color-base-contrast-3: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-background-2: rgb(244, 244, 244);
    --color-base-background-3: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    --color-base-background-4: rgb(222, 222, 222);
    --color-base-background-5: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    --color-green: hsl(165, 92%, 44%);
    --color-green-light: #77fcdb;
    --color-purple: rgb(121, 85, 243);
    --color-purple-light: #bd93f9;
    --color-yellow: rgb(246, 223, 104);
    --color-yellow-light: #f1fa8c;
    --color-red: rgb(238, 56, 96);
    --color-red-light: #ff5555;
    --color-blue: rgb(56, 201, 247);
    --color-blue-light: #8be9fd;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 0px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: var(--color-base-contrast-2);
    color: var(--color-light);
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    flex: 1 1;
}
  
.label {
    --color-dark: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-light: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color-base-contrast: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-contrast-2: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    --color-base-contrast-3: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --color-base-background-2: rgb(244, 244, 244);
    --color-base-background-3: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    --color-base-background-4: rgb(222, 222, 222);
    --color-base-background-5: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    --color-green: hsl(165, 92%, 44%);
    --color-green-light: #77fcdb;
    --color-purple: rgb(121, 85, 243);
    --color-purple-light: #bd93f9;
    --color-yellow: rgb(246, 223, 104);
    --color-yellow-light: #f1fa8c;
    --color-red: rgb(238, 56, 96);
    --color-red-light: #ff5555;
    --color-blue: rgb(56, 201, 247);
    --color-blue-light: #8be9fd;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 0px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
   <div class="container">
      <a class="link-side" href="/simplex">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line>
            <polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline>
         </svg>
         <span class="label">Simplex</span>
      </a>
      <a class="link" href="/">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="5"></line>
            <polyline points="5 12 12 5 19 12"></polyline>
         </svg>
      </a>
      <a class="link-side" href="/tessellation">
         <span class="label">Tessellation</span> 
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
            <polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline>
         </svg>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The "viewport" is set to be small like iPhone (even smaller for demo purposes), so it scrunches up the buttons. The buttons should be more along the lines like this (but with more padding on the left of the left button and right of the right button):

[image]

I'm not sure the algorithm that should take effect with the CSS engine, but both buttons on the left and right should be the same width (from `flex: 1`), and the middle button should fit the content. If the text is too large on either left or right button, it adds ellipses but keeps the `16px` padding on the left/right of the labels/arrows.

Right now it's not doing a bunch of things correctly:

1. It's growing the button on the right (the one with the longer text).
2. It's not ellipsifying the text.
3. It's not keeping the 16px padding on the left/right of the buttons around the label.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? I am using flexbox within the buttons to align the labels in the center, and outside of the buttons in the "button container" to layout the buttons in a row using flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use grid instead flex. This way you can define the grid from the parent instead letting it being built from the children showing up in the flow.

Here is an example :

```css
.viewport {
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: .75em;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono', monospace;
}

.container a {
  background: #5A5A5A;
  /*border-radius:5px;*/
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
}

.container .link-side {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.container .link-side:last-of-type {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.container a span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="link-side" href="/simplex">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line>
            <polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline>
         </svg>
      <span class="label">Simplex</span>
    </a>
    <a class="link" href="/">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="5"></line>
            <polyline points="5 12 12 5 19 12"></polyline>
         </svg>
    </a>
    <a class="link-side" href="/tessellation">
      <span class="label">Tessellation</span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
            <polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline>
         </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```